# CTRL-X CTRL-] does not work but CTRL-X CTRL-$ does

Tags: vimrc

To autocomplete using tags, I saw the combination <CTRL-]> in vim help `:help ins-completion`.

However, for some reason it does not work. I don't know how but I figured out that hitting <CTRL-$> does this tags autocompletion.

Knowing that this is what I run for vim

1. `ctags -R .`
2. `vim --no-plugin -u NONE`
3. `:syntax enabled`
4. `:filetype plugin on`
5. `:set path+=**`
6. `:set wildmenu`

Is it due to my azerty macos keyboard?

Comment: Yes, looks like on Azerty Ctrl+$ will generate that combination: https://superuser.com/q/377739/879179 That question also mentions Ctrl+AltGr+[. In Insert mode, you can type Ctrl+V followed by another sequence (like Ctrl+$) to see what it generates...

Comment: @filbranden thanks for your answer and for the link that describe the same thing.